# Change default size of search-replace box in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Search-replace. Something that one does aaaaaaaa looooooot. And every time I do it - I have to struggle with the tiny search-replace-pop-up window:

[image: small search-replace box in PHPstorm]

---

Is it possible to somehow set the default size to be a better size? Something like this:

[image: large search replace box in PHPstorm]

?

An extra annoyance is that the edges of that box have a very small area to grab, when resizing.

Comment: Yes, it's quite small in all new projects for me (I have quite large 1440p screen). But once resized it does remember the size and position (for that project). Are you saying that yours does not persist it?

Comment: You're right, once resized - it remembers that size (I wasn't aware of that). I have quite a lot of different projects though. It is quite a small thing, - but it would be amazing if I could solve it somehow.

Comment: I did some experiments with the stuff stored in `window.state.xml` file ... but they do not affect new projects in this regard at all. All sizes are project specific (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230812 or linked ticket) .. and right now I'm unable to find any tickets about wrong default size 9although I definitely remember seeing at least one). The best I can find right now is this: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260042

Comment: Feel free to file your own ticket and see what devs will say: if there is one they will mark as duplicate, no issues. Post the ticket number/your finding back here -- I'm interested in this as well.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the effort. I opened a ticket here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As can be seen in [The YouTrack ticket I created](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-58436#focus=Comments-27-4672604.0-0), a developer has responded that this featured does not exist.